# How to save language in session using php?

Tags: php, session

I want to save the language in a session using $_GET[''] method:

```
<a href="?lang=fr">French</a>
<a href="?lang=en">English</a>
```

By default the site language is in french. the site language will be changed if the user choose one from the links above. and then even thought the $_GET['lang'] is not set, i want the $_SESSION['lang'] always saves the last language choosen by the user.

I tried this but its not logic, i know..

```
$languages = array('en', 'fr');
if(isset($_GET['lang']) AND in_array($_GET['lang'], $languages)){
    $_SESSION['lang'] = $_GET['lang'];
}else{    
    $_SESSION['lang'] = "fr";    
}
require_once('languages/'.$_SESSION['lang'].'.php');
```

what should I do then to save the last language is session variable?

Comment: make sure you have `session_start()`

Comment: Its already there, 
The problem is when the $_GET['lang'] is set, the language changes, but when the user goes to another page, $_SESSION['lang'] equals "fr", the default language because i made the condition to change the language if the $_GET['lan'] issset and I don't want that, I want the $_SESSION['lang'] always keeps its last value and i justs didn't know the logic there

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What happens is when you don't have the language in url, it sets it back to french.

To fix this you set the language in session if it is given in url, otherwise if session is not set at all, you go by default, which is french.

```
$languages = array('en', 'fr');
if(isset($_GET['lang']) AND in_array($_GET['lang'], $languages)){
    $_SESSION['lang'] = $_GET['lang'];
}
if(!isset($_SESSION['lang']){    
    $_SESSION['lang'] = "fr";    
}
require_once('languages/'.$_SESSION['lang'].'.php');
```

Comment: Sidenote: since there's an `if`, `if(!isset($_SESSION['lang']){    
    $_SESSION['lang'] = "fr";    
}` could be changed to just `else { $_SESSION['lang'] = "fr"; }`.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Then when user navigates to other pages and language is not set in URL, it will go back to french instead of keeping last languages selected.